# Flask context processor doesn't work in an imported template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

These are the codes I've wrote:

**application.py**:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.context_processor
def inject_foo():
    return dict(foo='bar')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

**index.html**:

```
{% from 'macros.html' import print_foo %}
<p>print_foo: {{ print_foo() }}</p>
<p>foo(directly): {{ foo }}</p>
```

**macros.html**:

```
{% macro print_foo() %}
  foo is {{ foo }}
{% endmacro %}
```

And the files are structured like this:

```
flask-context-processor-issue/
    application.py
    templates/
        index.html
        macros.html
```

When I run the application(through `flask run`) and go to `http://localhost:5000`, I see this page:

```
print_foo: foo is
foo(directly): bar
```

`foo` for `print_foo` is missing. I think the reason is that `foo` is not visible inside the `print_foo` macro(which is in an imported template).

I can force `foo` to be globally visible by modify the `application.py`:

```
...
# @app.context_processor
# def inject_foo():
#     return dict(foo='bar')
app.jinja_env.globals['foo'] = 'bar'
...
```

But working along with `app.context_processor` is much general way I think, so I wonder is there any way to make the example works(with `app.context_processor`).

Waiting for your answer, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After looking closer at the documentation(http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/#context-processors), I've found that this should work:

**index.html**:

```
{% from 'macros.html' import print_foo with context %}
...
```

instead of

```
{% from 'macros.html' import print_foo %}
...
```

Dumb me.